# Stack Overflow has taken up religion!

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

On scrolling quickly through the all sites view, icons tend to get mixed up.

[image]

---

It's still happening as of version 0.1.31, in a different view this time.

[image]

Can't see it? Look at the first question in the image. [It's this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196616/still-having-issues-with-link-only-answer-flags).

Comment: This will do nothing to improve civility on Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, it seems to be an issue with how the views are recycled on Android, we'll fix it soon.

Comment: Oh, good ol' memory-saving table view cell reuse... I still hate you...

Comment: Oh... took me a while to understand what you meant by *"taken up religion"*. Nice joke, but honestly, there should be a better title. (You could move the joke into the description.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Stack Overflow will go back to being agnostic in the next version update, thanks!

**Update 2/25**: This should be even more fixed as of version 1.0.16. It was still happening sometimes on the site selector (dropdown when selecting a site to ask a question on) and sometimes in other views, as of the new update we're using a new third party image loading library ([Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)) which seems to have fixed this from happening anywhere.

Comment: Agnostic means you believe there is a god, but aren't sure of anything else. Or something else like that. Atheist means you don't believe in a god.

Comment: I'm not ready to make that definitive of a decision on behalf of SO. That requires a MSO discussion first.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, you are right about *athiest*, but *agnostic* does not mean that. It means you believe that whether or not any god(s) exist is uncertain, unknown, or perhaps even unknowable. People that believe in the existence of god(s), even if unsure of anything else, are not agnostic; they are definitely *theists*.

Comment: I think Stack Overflow's beliefs probably align with my own -- that the answer to the whole question is simply *Mu*. The premise and questions are so ill-defined that it allows for no logical answer and no logical reasoning about.

Comment: I thought the world was created by a unicorn, four thousand years ago?

Comment: yes, it was a Pink Unicorn, or the Invisible One... not sure about it...

Comment: So... [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217670/meta-is-japanese) should be status-completed now?

Comment: @hichris123 Yep! I'll answer on that one in a second. Currently going through the backlog of things that have already been fixed but have been neglected on meta...