# Why was my upvoted answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, specific-answer

My answer on [Using C# to check if string contains a string in string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912476/using-c-sharp-to-check-if-string-contains-a-string-in-string-array/18455074#18455074)
was deleted by a moderator despite having 1 up vote.

I would like to understand why?

Comment: It's a link-only answer. If that link were to go dead, your post has no worthwhile content.

Comment: The reference as a duplicate is incorrect. The referred question is about “not good answers”. A link alone  is a bad answer , that deserved to be improved or downvoted, but often does **not  deserved to be  deleted**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is a link-only answer to a blog post without any explanation. [Link-only answers are not answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

- They look like spam.
- Links go dead.
- Nobody really wants to follow a link and possibly have to sift through it to get their answer.

Answers should stand on their own, with links as support (or not at all). You can edit your answer to summarize the contents of your link so that it’s useful without it, and then flag it for undeletion.

---

Performance might also be better as a comment, but you don’t have enough reputation for that, so it might be best to leave that kind of thing (especially when the question is old and already answered) for later.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the clarification. If it gets undeleted will the upticks remain and the reputation score adjusted as appropriate? Or will counters be reset?

Comment: If you improve the post enough to warrent undeletion, it will exist as it was... meaning the post score at the time of deletion will remain

Comment: Also, sort of related, there are 15 other deleted answers pretty much just like that one by this user.

Comment: ^ Yep, and answer-blocked. Ask when in doubt!

Comment: What about flags? Apparently there are only 10 flags? If we flag an answer, does the flag count get reset if approved by a moderator?

Comment: @FireMyst: Yes, it does.

Comment: One last question (for now :-) )...will we receive notification when a flagged post is reviewed and/or updated by a moderator?

Comment: @FireMyst: Nope — it’s a matter of checking your flag history (click on the number in your profile page). But if you comment here, I’ll get to it faster :)

Comment: @minitech I totally agree with your answer (*Link-only answers are not answers*). I usually flag these kinds of answers as *It is not an answer* (and my flags are generally accepted) but since I received -5 to my answer to this [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198655) and after reading comments, I am lost and I stopped to flag. It seems that everybody (including mods) doesn't have the same opinion about link-only answers and what should be do with them (I refuse personally to see the link and edit someone else's answer like proposed). So, flag or not? and if yes which flag?

Comment: @Chris: I agree – NAA is the right flag – but I have no clue how to deal with the disagreement problem. Sorry. Maybe we’ll get a new flag reason.

Comment: @minitech Don't be sorry :) and I agree that a new specific flag would be useful in order to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @minitech: ok, commenting here as requested to check the flags. I've revised both posts that were in question. Also, as noted under my original question, is there a ways to have the moderators make a judgement call and hopefully reverse the down voting on my original question? I think it's uncalled for to have a question down voted when we're trying to understand how the site works -- it detracts from the site and discourages users from asking questions. :(

Comment: @FireMyst: Voting is a key part of SE. We don’t change people’s opinions lightly. Sorry. As for your edit, the answer still doesn’t stand alone. Try to at least include the code of the fastest method and the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Minitech: in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498686/is-string-contains-faster-than-string-indexof/18455416#18455416 I did include code of the fastest technique, so am not sure what else you're looking for? I can't explain *why* that code is faster than the other techniques because I'm no expert in getting into the bits and bytes of underlying data, memory operations, and other processes. In that example, I would expect the code that ran the fastest to not have been because of all the memory allocations it has to do for strings and memory. The other has been resubmitted again. Thx.

Comment: I’m only undeleting one (where it’s most relevant), but is this your blog or something? It really looks like spam when you have so many answers that link to the same blog, and in that case it’s almost better to not include the link/not bother answering…

Comment: @Minitech: it's my friend's blog. In the posting "Is String.Contains() faster than String.IndexOf()?" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498686/is-string-contains-faster-than-string-indexof/18455416#18455416, I would think it's completely relevant because the original question was asking about performance between two native C# methods. That particular blog post benchmarks the two methods in question along with other techniques. So I don't see why it's *not* considered relevant?

Comment: @FireMyst: Pick one. Two is spam. Sorry.

Comment: @minitech: it's obviously more relevant with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498686/is-string-contains-faster-than-string-indexof/18455416#18455416 Thank you. :-)

Comment: @minitech: it doesn't appear my "flag" has been credited when you reinstated the answer. Are you able to confirm?

Comment: Link in the answer “[Link-only answers are not answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) incorrectly describes the referred question “ are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really **good-answers**”