# Hitting phone's back button causes mismatch between site icon and title

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Using the Android app, I can cause the site icon and title to become out of sync with the following steps:

1. Click on the top icon and select a site. (Stack Overflow for example)
2. Click on the top icon again and select a different site. (MSO for example)
3. Hit the phone's back button.

Using the above examples, I would see the SO icon, accompanied by "Meta Stack Overflow".

[image]

Android version is 4.3 and app version is 0.1.64.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack Overflow has taken up religion!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194725/stack-overflow-has-taken-up-religion)

Comment: That doesn't seem like the same bug. (And that one should've been fixed already - that was in 0.1.31, this is happening in 0.1.64)

Comment: It appears that the proposed duplicate relates to the "All Sites" screen. This one doesn't. I did just add a screenshot of the resultant behavior, to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This bug (which by the way, was not a duplicate of the other one!) has been fixed and will be released in version 0.1.66 coming out tonight.

Comment: Awesome, I'll accept this answer tonight upon verification!