# Meta is... Japanese?

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

[This bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194725/stack-overflow-has-taken-up-religion) appears to have cropped up again. I'm using version 1.0.2 of the app. When scrolling quickly down and back up the network sites in the Android app, I got this:

[image]

I'm sorry, but I don't speak Japanese. That means I have to quit meta now. Goodbye. :P Seriously, can this bug be fixed? Also, why did the bug crop up again in the first place?

Comment: I take it you're not bothered by Super User being Jewish then? What do you have against the Japanese, anyway?

Comment: @Shog9 Religion has already been covered in another post. This is for another people group. :P And I like the English and Spanish, at least I know their language. :P

Comment: I'm more concerned about SO being represented as a... gear thingy....

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow That's [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/).

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194725/stack-overflow-has-taken-up-religion. Possible regression?

Comment: Lol, ok. Anyway, [tag:status-norepro] here

Comment: @Doorknob Just go to all-sites, scroll down really fast and then scroll up very fast. Just repro'ed it now.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce, I'm using a Galaxy S4 with Android 4.3

Comment: Weird, Nexus 7 with 4.4.2 here.

Comment: Test comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219656/site-selection-drop-down-is-locked-up-when-choosing-sites-to-pin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

View recycling is fun!

As of version 1.0.16 we're using a new third party image loading library ([Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)) which seems to have fixed these sort of issues.